# Python using 'OR with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have to test if a string is within my criteria. Currently, I have this:

```
answer = bool(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]',string))
```

This works fine, however the user also needs to be able to have another type of answer validated. Would you have to do this:

```
answer2 = bool(re.findall'[1-9][^A-Z]',string))
```

then use an IF statement like this:

```
if answer1 or answer2:
```

Or is there an easier more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Just looking for a single substring? Don't know python but isn't there just a simple `find` for that? Also, you seem to know what a character class is. Did you know that character classes are inherintly OR'd characters?

Comment: @sln I can't use a simple 'find' because I am not looking for a certain string but a string that matches certain criteria.

Comment: Does a simple find use a regex? A simple regex _is_ your criteria `[A-Z1-9][^A-Z]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
answer = bool(re.findall('(?:[A-Z]|[1-9])[^A-Z]',cad))
```

Comment: Just a little change [`(?:[A-Z]|[0-9]|10)[^A-Z]`](https://www.debuggex.com/i/AJz-LgKl9BOGw9-s.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course:

```
answer = bool(re.findall('(?:[A-Z]|[0-9])[^A-Z]',string))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a single character class:

```
answer = bool(re.findall('[A-Z0-9][^A-Z]',string))
```